# Using Always Encrypted Inside STORED PROCEDURE SQL SERVER

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, always-encrypted

I'm trying to execute SP with DETERMINISTIC type encrypted column.
I get the following error:

> Msg 206, Level 16, State 2, Procedure sp_ConvertCard_advancedSearch, Line 0 [Batch Start Line 22]
>
> Operand type clash: varchar is incompatible with nvarchar(50) encrypted with (encryption_type = 'DETERMINISTIC', encryption_algorithm_name = 'AEAD_AES_256_CBC_HMAC_SHA_256', column_encryption_key_name = 'idan_test_col', column_encryption_key_database_name = 'db_name')
>
> Msg 206, Level 16, State 2, Procedure sp_ConvertCard_advancedSearch, Line 0 [Batch Start Line 22]
>
> Operand type clash: varchar is incompatible with nvarchar(50) encrypted with (encryption_type = 'DETERMINISTIC', encryption_algorithm_name = 'AEAD_AES_256_CBC_HMAC_SHA_256', column_encryption_key_name = 'idan_test_col', column_encryption_key_database_name = 'db_name')

The Stored Procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_ConvertCard_advancedSearch]
       @token nvarchar(50) = null
AS 

SET NOCOUNT ON
BEGIN
   -- Insert statements for procedure here

                           SELECT
                                  *
                           FROM
                                  ConvertCard
                           WHERE
                                  Token = @token
 
              -- order by
             
                           ORDER BY Id DESC
 
END
```

So my question is how can I execute this SP in right way for that to work?

- I am using Enable Parameterization for Always Encrypted
- I Added Column Encryption Setting = Enabled in the Additional Connection Parameters in the SSMS

Comment: https://sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix

Comment: The error is telling you the problem too. Clearly `Token` isn't an `nvarchar`. If you are querying a `varchar`, you should never pass an `nvarchar` anyway; it ruins SARGability.

Comment: token is nvarchar also. im passing 'test' like this so its converted to varchar i supposed

Comment: What is the definition of `ConvertCard`?

Answer (score 0):

Well, the "problem" was that i've tried to execute the stored procedure like

`exec [sp_ConvertCard_advancedSearch] '123456789'`

When i executed it from visual studio via SqlCommand parameters it worked.

thanks.